# Reading the Binary Data from JMeter sampler

Tags: java, io, jmeter, binary-data, beanshell

Trying to read the Binary data response from JMeter sampler and deserialize it in the BeanShlll Post Processor.

The flow is, controller first sends a request to a webservice, which returns binary data.
When I view that in the JMeter, I see some junk chars.

I need to convert this to the actual object (my custom object) in the BeanShell script.

This is what I tried. But no luck. Or may be I am trying something dumb.
PS: Newbie with IO stuff.

```
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import com.package.MyClass;

 MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

 myObj = ois.readObject();
```

It does not work. It does not show anything.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `readObject` method works on that binary data? For example don't i.e. StreamCorruptedException occur and your post-processor stops working.

As per How to use [BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide

> As Beanshell is executed within Rhino engine there is no other option to see what’s wrong apart from inspecting jmeter.log file for something like: Error invoking bsh method and using System.out.println(“something”) or log.info(“something”) to get to the bottom of where the script fails.

you don't have a way to verify whether your post-processor is successful, you'll have to look into the logs and/or add some debug output statement to the end.

Another technique which can be useful is surrounding your code with `try/catch`

See example below on how to use. In case of "everything is fine" the post processor will print `Successfully read data into myObj` into STDOUT. In opposite case you'll see a relevant error stacktrace there.

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        Object myObj = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully read data into myObj"); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used readObjext for similar thing and it works. Just not in this case. Thanks

Comment: What does jmeter.log say? Any beanshell-related errors? Any exceptions in stdout when your code wrapped into try/catch block? Is `MyClass` jar in JMeter classpath?

Comment: It just does not show anything. Even with try/catch. For now, I just save the response to a file and read that file with InputStream. It works.